# How can exporting EDITOR="nano visudo" be considered a severe security risk in the context of visudo?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, security, sudo, vi

Reading a [security guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Security) on how to harden Arch Linux, I've come across the following tip that exporting `EDITOR=nano visudo` is considered a severe security risk.

> **Tip:**
>
> To use restricted version of `nano` instead of `vi` with `visudo` [add to `/etc/sudoers`],
>
> ```
> Defaults editor=/usr/bin/rnano
> ```
>
> Exporting `EDITOR=nano visudo` is regarded as a severe security risk since everything can be used as an `EDITOR`.

I'm not sure why that is mentioned in the context of specifying `visudo`'s default editor using `Defaults editor=/user/bin/rnano` in `/etc/sudoers`?

Furthermore, shouldn't `$EDITOR` specify only a single editor, or is it a convention that it may specify multiple editors separated by spaces?

Since `EDITOR=nano visudo` doesn't specify the full path, it may be exploited by putting any binary called `nano` in the current directory, but how can that be used to exploit `visudo`?

Bonus: Shouldn't the guide be corrected to using quotes, as in `EDITOR="nano visudo"`, to set `$EDITOR`?

Comment: Could using merely `nano` be a security risk, due to the full path not being specified, e.g. should be `/usr/bin/nano` ?  Otherwise any old dodgy malicious binary that someone calls `nano` could potentially get picked up.

Comment: @steve - Why would anyone include `visudo` in `$EDITOR`? I guess, what you are saying is what I'm already saying in the question, but I don't see why it's mentioned in the context of `visudo`?

Comment: For the record, `EDITOR="nano visudo"` is totally wrong. `EDITOR="nano" visudo` could be right

Comment: running `EDITOR=nano visudo` like that on the shell command line, would run `visudo`, with the envvar `EDITOR` set to `nano`, and you could put whatever you want there in place of `nano`. But I'm not sure how that's a problem, as far as I can understand, `visudo` in itself doesn't give any privileges, so you might as well try and run `nano /etc/sudoers` directly (and fail). And whatever editor you use to edit `sudoers`, you can always just put whatever you want in there... What am I missing?

Comment: @ilkkachu - I guess, the tip in Arch Linux documentation is written under the assumption that `visudo` is a suid executable.

Answer (score 1):

`EDITOR=nano visudo`  simply runs `visudo`, telling it to search your `$PATH` for the editor to use. Since `$PATH` is under `$USER`'s control, ...

The hope is that `visudo` will run `$EDITOR` as `root` and Own The World.

In general, executables whose name doesn't begin with "`/`" are found with this pseudocode:

```
# executing "nano"
for p in $( echo $PATH | tr ':' ' ' ) ; do
    [[ -x $p/nano ]] && exec $p/nano
done
```

Thus, if there is an executable named `nano` in a directory earlier in `$PATH` than `/usr/bin`, it will be executed. That's why you should use `editor=/usr/bin/nano visudo` instead.

The current directory. "`.`" should NOT be included automatically in the above pseudocode. One could, but shouldn't, put "`.`" in your `$PATH`. If I trick you into `cd /media/$USER/Found` (where the USB key you found in the parking lot automounts), with "`.`" early in `$PATH`, and there is my script named `nano` in that directory. `EDITOR=nano visudo` will run `./nano` (my `nano`). Game Over.

Comment: I do not see the usefulness of this answer (yet), could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: @waltinator - shouldn't the current directory also be part of your pseudo code?